# free allocated memory of array (vs normal var?)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I know that when we're allocating memory for a var, we need to free the space by calling free() func with the pointer to the var (and not leaving the pointer dangling).

But what do we do when we allocate memory for array of vars?
Should we go and free each member of the array[0..n], or is it enough just to free the pointer for the first member?

```
long *array_p; 
size_t elements_num = 5

array_p = malloc(elements_num*sizeof(long));
```

option #1:

```
free(array_p);
array_p=NULL;
```

option #2:

```
for (i=0; i<array_len-1; ++i)
{
    free(array_p+i);
    array_p+i= NULL;
}
```

Comment: You need to call `free()` as many times as `malloc()` was invoked.

Comment: Did you allocate the elements seperately? If no, what makes you think you have to free the seperately? Please provide a [mcve]. And what is a "var"?

Comment: malloc() was called once to create the whole array (of my elements) 'array_p =malloc(num_of_elements*element_size)' I am not sure if free the pointer that points to this array will free the whole array, all or only the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operating systems usually work this way: Every memory allocation leaves a trace in the memory chunk —in addition to your actual / real data size (which include some additional info, like the length of the memory allocated, the next available memory address for the coming allocation, etc). To be specific,

- when you allocate a chunk of **40 characters**, the OS will allocate 56 bytes —16 bytes in order to keep track of the length of the memory allocated, the next available (free) memory address, etc. and 40 bytes for your actual data.
- when you allocate a chunk of **40 integers**, this time however, the OS will allocate 176 bytes —again, 16 bytes in order to keep track of the length of the memory allocated, the next available (free) memory address, etc. and (4 × 40 =) 160 bytes for your actual data.

So, when you free an array of data, the OS will already be aware of the starting and ending addresses of the memory to be freed.

The first 20 minutes of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nYDflSL0Mg) video explains the procedure very well in detail.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not if you are allocating an array, but if you are allocating an array of pointers.

You need a `free` for each `malloc`/`calloc` you use. Now In a situation like

```
int* array = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
```

You have a continuous block of 10 `int` in memory and you need just a `free(array)`.

But you could have an

```
int** arrayOfArray = calloc(10, sizeof(int*));
```

Now you have an array of 10 `int*`, so pointers to `int`. In a real case scenario your array can't be used, you must assign or allocate each element of the array, eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  arrayOfArray[i] = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
```

So each element of the first array is a pointer that points to a contiguous block of memory for 5 `int`. In this situation you have two evel of allocations and indeed you need two level of deallocations, in reverse order, eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  free(arrayOfArray[i]);

free(arrayOfArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not array of pointers, just a normal array... I will edit my questions so it will be more cleared

Comment: If it's a normal array you just need a single free, the OS knows the correct size for the pointed block of memory so no additional work needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

> but what do we do when we allocate memory for array of vars? should we
>   go and free each member of the array[0..n],

Yes, you have to `free()` each of the pointers allocated in the array.

> or is it enough just to free the pointer for the first member?

No.

For example,

```
char *p[50];

for(i = 0; i<50;i++)
p[i] = malloc(10); 


for(i = 0; i<50;i++)
free(p[i]);
```

---

```
char **p;

p = malloc(50 * sizeof(char*));

for(i = 0; i<50;i++)
p[i] = malloc(10); 

for(i = 0; i<50;i++)
free(p[i]);

free(p);
```

Basically, for every call to `malloc()`, you have one call to `free()`.

Comment: For me the (attempt at) assignment `array_p+i= NULL;` means that the OP only allocated one array. If they allocated n blocks and stored the addresses in an array, they'd know how to assign `array_p[i]`.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer and the good edits :)

I am not sure i understood your comment. 
As for my (little) knowladge, the pointers  p+1...p+n will now store addresses which are no good (= dangling pointers). 
Don't we need to correct it?

Comment: @MichalKandel Do you mean assigning NULL to them after `free()`ing? Assigning NULL is not necessary. It's more of a practice some follow. As long as you don't access those pointers after `free()`ing, you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know what you're creating when you create an array of variables. In C, a pointer acts like an array and so you therefore need to traverse the whole array, freeing each member, and then free the pointer for the first member. Simply freeing the point to the first member without freeing each member of the array will usually result in a memory leak, which could eventually result in your programs running slowly and eventually crashing or modifying/accessing data which you do not intend to modify (segmentation faults).

Answer (score 0):

You just pass the pointer to the first element (which is what malloc has given you) to free:

```
int * array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
....
free(array);
```